# wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 when launching a game installed by steam in linux

Tags: shared-library, steam

I've installed "Counter-strike global offensive" from steam store in linux ubuntu 18.04 but when I launch it (from terminal) , it gives numerous errors like the following :

```
Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/bin/datacache_client.so

error=Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/bin/datacache_client.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

From already answered questions I've already known that I should install 32-bit shared objects but most of those libraries (if not all) aren't available in the repository and is created by the game developers.

I want to know what can I do to suppress these errors?
Also it cannot be launched from steam app directly.
Your help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally removing all 32-bit shared objects (temporarily) which were resided under bin/ of the root game directory solved the problem.I think it's a bug within the game itself.
Also I cannot install much of those libraries from the repository since they are proprietary shared objects for that game.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "suppress these errors": an executable binary and all the libraries it requires must be either all 64-bit or all 32-bit. In order to run the application, you must provide correct versions of all the libraries it needs.

If your system is 64-bit and you haven't installed any 32-bit libraries before, you will probably need to enable the 32-bit architecture support in the package management system:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

You might also have to check your repository definitions in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files. If there are any uncommented lines with architecture specification, i.e. like this:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://...
```

then you might wish to remove the ''[arch=amd64]'' part that restricts package repository access to 64-bit versions only.

After that, run `sudo apt update` or equivalent command to refresh the lists of available packages, and then you should have the 32-bit versions of any library packages available for selection with the same name as a corresponding 64-bit package, but with a `:i386` suffix after the package name.

Comment: Thanks for your long explanation but I cannot install some of those packages using apt.Those aren't belong to the repository.